# How to dm everyone in a server using interval

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to make an interval that dm's every 10 min to a random person in a suggest server. And when my bot has had them all, that he sends a message that it's completed.

Here is my code, but it don't work.

```
if (message.guild && message.content.startsWith('dmall'))


    var ServerID = bot.guilds.get("653024542759059456");

  var interval = setInterval(function () {

    let text = message.content.slice('dmall '.length);
    message.guild.members.forEach(member => {
      if (member.id != bot.user.id && !member.user.bot) member.send(text);

      //stop the interval
      clearInterval(interval);
      //here you can handle the all done logic
      console.log("I'm done, mate!");


    }, 60000);
  });
```

Comment: Your code seems incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you forgot the closing `});` of your `forEach` method.

I've fixed that:

```
setInterval(() => {
  var guildList = bot.guilds.array();
  guildList.forEach(member => {
    member.send("test");
  });
}, 600000);
```

But the code above sends "test" to each member in the guilds array. I am not sure if you want to pick a random member of the array and send only to him and if that's the case this might work:

```
setInterval(() => {
  var guildList = bot.guilds.array();
  let member = guildList[Math.floor(Math.random() * guildList.length)];
  member.send("test");
}, 600000);
```

That just picks only one random element from the guildList array and sends a message to him. I am not sure if this is going to work in your case since I don't have the whole context.

**UPDATE:**
Here's a way to handle the guildList globally, pop a random user and send a message for completion once all members were sent a message.

```
const guildList = bot.guilds.array();

let interval = setInterval(() => {
    //pick a random member and remove it from the list  
    let member = guildList.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * guildList.length), 1);
    member.send("test");
    //stop the interval
    if(guildList.length == 0){ 
        clearInterval(interval);
        //here you can handle the all done logic
        console.log("I'm done, mate!");
    }
}, 600000);
```

Comment: You're welcome, if it works for you, please accept the answer so others can use the solution too.

Comment: that's very hard to reproduce... can you share your full code snippet